# Silverlight Panorama Control: Control overlap?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

In this image, the content from one panorama item bleeds over onto the previous item:

[image: wp7 panorama]

How can I do this in Expression Blend / with XAML?

Here is my XAML currently:

```
    <controls:Panorama Margin="0,0,-1732,8" Grid.Row="1" Title="ODP">
        <controls:PanoramaItem Header="new">
            <local:StoryList/>
        </controls:PanoramaItem>
        <controls:PanoramaItem Header="few">
            <local:StoryList/>
        </controls:PanoramaItem>
                    <!-- ... -->
```

It works, but the content doesn't overlap so it's harder for the user to know they can scroll over.

Comment: what do you mean the content doesn't overlap? that shown above *is* the panorama control, and if i make a new panorama app from the supplied panorama template, the content on the second panorama does show on the edge.

Comment: and why the massive negative margin in your code snippet?

Comment: @John Gardner when I made a new panorama app using the supplied template, there was no overlap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it because you have a margin set on your panorama?  or because you appear to have more things in your grid?

Why do you have the panorama in row 1?  what's in row 0?

the sample by default has this:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">

    <!--Panorama control-->
    <controls:Panorama Title="my application">
        <controls:Panorama.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="PanoramaBackground.png"/>
        </controls:Panorama.Background>
```

with no margin and *no other controls* in the grid.

Comment: Incidentally, when I use that method to get an image background, the image is horizontally squished and repeated on every panorama item. Are there strict requirements on image size?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the width of your panorama item. 
If it is less than the width of the screen, you should be able to view it. If it is more than the width of the screen, it may be cropped off unless you specify to make it span more than 1 page.

If you can't see the next page, I suspect you enabled the spanning accidentally.